# Microsoft Office 2010 Proofing Tools Kit

Tags: microsoft-office, spell-check, microsoft-office-2010, proofing

I have installed the Office 2010 available on MSDN, but there is no proofing tools kit available there yet. Still I see various sources where I can download this kit when I search for it on Google.

Is the Proofing Tools Kit available yet or not? Are these sources I see on Google legitimate ones or should I stay away from them? Or are they also available from Microsoft directly somewhere I haven't looked yet?

**2010-07-28 Bump:** Has anything come out now? I found something called a language pack on MSDN, but the installation looked pretty much the same as the original... not quite sure what that pack did...

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this where it gives you various proofing tools for languages, like Spanish, French, etc? If so, you install these using the "Custom" install method. IIRC, they're not installed by default if you do the "Express" (?) install method.

Comment: Yes, but the default installer only includes this for Spanish, French, English and possibly a few more. To get it for other languages you either need a localized version or the proofing tools kit.